# Function works as expected when called from function using XMLHttpRequest, but fails when called from a function using EventSource. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, chat

I'm working on creating a basic messenger using Javascript. I have three functions in a separate js file called `loadMessage`, `messageListener`, and `displayMessage`.

The function `loadMessage` makes a call to my database for all existing messages, and then calls `displayMessages` to construct some divs which I use to show the messages I got from the server. These divs are created to appear under each other, with the bottom div being the newly created one showing the latest message.

Once all the messages have been created `loadMessage` then calls `messageListener`. This function 'listens' for any new messages which might appear on the database. If any appear then `messageListener` calls `displayMessage`. I expect this to create a new div at the bottom of my other divs as before, however when it calls `displayMessage` the behaviour is completely different than when `loadMessage` calls `displayMessage`.

Specifically, it does not create a new div but instead just changes the text in an existing div which appears anywhere within the newly created divs (for example, the div which displays the first message or one somewhere in the middle).

My HTML and PHP files all behave as expected, so I think my issue is somewhere in these three functions.

How can I fix this to behave as expected?

Code:

```
 // Loads chat messages history and listens for upcoming ones.
function loadMessages(userID, contactID) {
    contactIDGlobal = contactID;
    //load existing messages
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    var param = "userID="+userID+"&contactID="+contactID+"&date="+date;

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","Interface-getMessage.php?", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(param);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //retrives a string of all past messages
    var messageString = xmlhttp.responseText;
    //parse string to get messages. 
    var parseMessageString = messageString.split('-');
    for (var i = 0; parseMessageString[i] !== null && parseMessageString[i] !== ''; i = i+5){
      var contactID = parseMessageString[i];
      var senderID = parseMessageString[i+1];
      var message = parseMessageString[i+2];
      var time = parseMessageString[i+3];
      var mID = parseMessageString[i+4];
      displayMessage(userID, senderID, contactID, message, date, time, mID);
    }
  }
};
//listen for new messages
    messageListener(userID, contactID);   
}


function messageListener(userID, contactID){
    if(typeof(EventSource)!=="underfined") {
        var newMessage = new EventSource("testerfile.php?userID="+userID+"&contactID="+contactID);
        newMessage.onmessage = function(event) {
          var newMessageData = event.data;
          var parseNewMessage = newMessageData.split('-');
          //sender ID may be different to the userID due to the way that messages are stored on the server. Received messages have a different sender.
          var senderID = parseNewMessage[0];
          var contactID = parseNewMessage[1];
          var message = parseNewMessage[2];
          var date = parseNewMessage[3];
          var time = parseNewMessage[4];
          var messageID = parseNewMessage[5];

          console.log(event.data);
          displayMessage(userID, senderID, contactID, message, date, time, messageID);      
        };
    }else {
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "Your browser does not support this";
    } 

    }

// Displays a Message in the UI.
function displayMessage(userID, senderID, contactID, nMessage, date, time, id){
  var messageListElement = document.getElementById('messages');
  var messageInputElement = document.getElementById('message');
  // If an element for this message already exists, then get it
  var id = id;
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  // If an element for that message does not exists yet we create it.
  if (!div) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    if (userID == senderID){
      container.innerHTML = SENDER_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE;
    }else{
      container.innerHTML = MESSAGE_TEMPLATE;
      }
    div = container.firstChild;
    div.setAttribute('id', id);
    for (var i = 0; i < messageListElement.children.length; i++) {
      var child = messageListElement.children[i];
    }
    messageListElement.insertBefore(div, child);
  }
  var messageElement = div.querySelector('.message');
  messageElement.textContent = nMessage;
  // Replace all line breaks by <br>.
  messageElement.innerHTML = messageElement.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
}


// Template for messages.
var SENDER_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE =
    '<div class="sender_message-container">' +
      '<div class="message"></div>' +
    '</div>';

var MESSAGE_TEMPLATE =
    '<div class="message-container">' +
      '<div class="message"></div>' +
    '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the date being returned as y-m-d, and the parser using "-". This mean I was creating a time var which was the month of my date, and the message ID as the day. I made the alteration below to fix this...

```
  var newMessageData = event.data;
  var parseNewMessage = newMessageData.split('-');
  //sender ID may be different to the userID due to the way that messages are stored on the server. Received messages have a different sender.
  var senderID = parseNewMessage[0];
  var contactID = parseNewMessage[1];
  var message = parseNewMessage[2];
  var date = parseNewMessage[3]+"-"+parseNewMessage[4]+"-"+parseNewMessage[5];
  var time = parseNewMessage[6];
  var messageID = parseNewMessage[7];
```